# Tensorflow: Replacing/feeding a placeholder of a graph with tf.Variable?

Tags: tensorflow, placeholder

I have a model `M1` whose data input is a placeholder `M1.input` and whose weights are trained. 
My goal is to build a new model `M2` which computes the output `o` of `M1` (with its trained weights) from an input `w` in a form of `tf.Variable` (instead of feeding actual values to `M1.input`). In other words, I use the trained model `M1` as a black-box function to build a new model `o = M1(w)` (in my new model, `w` is to be learned and the weights of `M1` are fixed as constants). The problem is that `M1` only accepts as its input `M1.input` through which we need to feed actual values, not a tf.Variable like `w`.

As a naive solution to build `M2`, I can just manually build `M1` within `M2` and then initialize `M1`'s weights with the pre-trained values and keep them not trainable within `M2`. However, in practice, `M1` is complicated and I don't want to manually build `M1` again within `M2`. I am looking for a more elegant solution, something like a workaround or a direct solution to replace the input placeholder `M1.input` of `M1` with tf.Variable `w`.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. What about:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


def M1(input, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('model_1', reuse=reuse):
        param = tf.get_variable('param', [1])
        o = input + param
        return o


w = tf.get_variable('some_w', [1])
plhdr = tf.placeholder_with_default(w, [1])

output_m1 = M1(plhdr)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    sess.run(w.assign([42]))

    print(sess.run(output_m1, {plhdr: [0]}))  # direct from placeholder
    print(sess.run(output_m1))                # direct from variable
```

So when feed_dict has a value for the placeholder, this value is used. Otherwise, the fallback option using the variable "w" is active.